# Using NPM Install

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to use npm install -g create-react-app, and each time I get a checkPermissions with code EACCESS.

Node Version 12.16.3 and its Mac OS Catalina. I used the Node.JS website to download the installer.

[image: Terminal Error]

Comment: Which version of Node/npm, installed how, and on which OS?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Node Version 12.16.3 and its Mac OS Catalina. I used the Node.JS website to download the installer.

Comment: Thank you, but remember to put that in your post: comments for additional information are typically because the post lacked necessary details, so make sure to edit =)

Comment: And with that information supplled: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: And with that information supplled: the `npm` documentation has a special page dedicated specifically to this problem: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally - the official recommendation is to use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) ([nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) on windows).

Comment: I leave an upvote to your post, I hope you motivate with this and keep going on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a package with ‘-g’ global tag may require additional permissions depending on your roles and settings. Use `npx` instead of `npm` for this. `npx` will not install create-react-app but it will execute it allowing you to create react app without installing the package. E.g. `npx create-react-app app-name`

Comment: Thanks for the options. Is there any way you know of that I can give my account the access it needs to install -g without having to use sudo?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue when using node and npm on Mac/Linux.
I fixed this issue by using nvm. you can check [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script) for more detail.

Steps:
First, remove all installed `node` and `npm modules`.
Second, install `nvm`.
Third, install node/npm using `nvm install ...`. for example, I installed node v12, so `nvm install v12`.

Then, install global packages using npm.
ex: `npm install -g create-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Just try Npx

```
npx create-react-app projectName
```

Npx does the same thing but the only difference is that you dont need to install anything globally in the system.

I would not prefer sudo for npm packages mostly.

Comment: normally, yes, but the whole point of `create-react-app` is to be a task runner that _builds_ repos, so in this case `npx` is not a recommendable solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, and the `npm` documentation even has a page dedicated specifically to understanding and fixing this problem. Head on over to https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally for their help with this.

However, the tl;dr is that the official recommendation is to use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (or [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) for when you're on windows), which should completely solve this problem as those explicitly install Node/npm in your user's part of the file system, rather than in a location that is generally reserved for `root`.

Comment: Thanks I will check that out, I just uninstalled all instances of node/node_modules so I will go with the nvm route

Comment: If you use Node, `nvm` is basically a must. It solves a _lot_ of problems, and lets you have multiple versions of Node installed so you can make sure to match your local dev runtime to whatever you're forced to use in production, with a simple `nvm use ...` command.